# can't access array of objects in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm baffled about why I'm getting an error when trying to access an array inside of an object in ReactJS.

I am using Redux to store an object in State.

I have a success function that allows the page to render, so by the time I get to this object it has for sure loaded. (I noticed a ton of similar questions to this where that's usually the problem).

When I do this I get the proper results:

```
const { events } = this.props
console.log(JSON.stringify(events.listSignup))

{"data":[{"eventID":"264712106049274377","name":"BookOne","email":null,"verify":null,"privacy":null,"order":null,"group":null},{"eventID":"264712106049274377","name":"BookTwo","email":null,"verify":null,"privacy":null,"order":null,"group":null}]}
```

I can see that the array "data" exists, but when I try:

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(events.listSignup.data[0].name))
```

or

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(events.listSignup.data[0]))
```

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what's going on. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: what does : `console.log(events)` show in the debugger?

Comment: If you're getting that JSON from that `console.log` statement, `events.listSignup.data[0].name` is absolutely correct, so these statements must be separated from one another in some way such that `events.listSignup`'s value or contents change before the second statement you're doing, otherwise the second one would be working. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: if you can, it'd be more useful to put a breakpoint in your browser debugger and watch. my best guess is that you've a first render with no data, and a second with data.

Comment: What you describe is impossible. If the logs were in the same block and executed at the same time. I suggest logging the following: `console.log('signup',JSON.stringify(events.listSignup));console.log('data',JSON.stringify(events.listSignup?.data))`

Comment: Seconding what @y_nk said, that's the usual reason. If you look in the console, you'll probably find a previous (or subsequent) output from that `console.log(JSON.stringify(events.listSignup))` that doesn't have the data, and it's there you're getting the problem.

Comment: Copied that exact data literal into a variable `foo` in the console and `foo.data[0].name` // "BookOne". It's correct. What else is going on with that object in your code?

Comment: on a non-directly-related matter, but still.

it's usually not a good practice to pass nested data structures into your component like this. you may want to go straight to the point and provide useful data without exploring a substructure, in case that data structure changes. try to evolve your component to consume directly "events.listSignup.data" as a prop of your component. doing so will enable elegant defaultProps (an empty array) and also a ternary statement on upper level to avoid displaying the component if no data (which is a pretty common usage)

Comment: Ok, so there is a first one running where it outputs "Undefined", I guess I was just staring at it so long (and it's 3am) I just missed it. I'm still not sure how it's running, but I guess I know where to look to start tomorrow. Thanks everyone for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be baffled, because what you [think you] have observed isn't possible.

This happens a lot to me as a developer, and my advice is that when this happens, trust your knowledge (you *know* this isn't possible!) and double check what you are seeing.

I suspect that the first time your component renders, `this.props.events` is `undefined`, but then it very quickly re-renders with `this.props.events` being set.

I would suggest adding back this line (without the others):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(events.listSignup))
```

And scrolling up in your javascript console to see if you have any logs that are just displaying `undefined`. If so, you probably need to double check the logic which is preventing the page from rendering before you have successfully received the data, as I suspect that is where your problem is.

Comment: Ok, so there is a first one running where it outputs "Undefined", I guess I was just staring at it so long (and it's 3am) I just missed it. I'm still not sure how it's running early, but I guess I know where to start to frustratingly look tomorrow. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Fixed it. The problem is that I forgot to return "...state" first in my new redux reducer so it was wiping out all my data when called X-x Bonehead 3am mistake. Thanks for the help, I would've gone mad without you pointing this out.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Sounds like a very easy mistake to make!